# Volley request not taking parameters

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a custom volley request, but it didn't take my params when sending request, what's wrong with my code?
I set a breakpoint at `getParams`  and `getPostParams`, but none of them went through.

I used `com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+`  which is forked from google volley to support maven.

I find the class worked well at real device but cann't work at genymotion.

```
public class GsonRequest<T> extends Request<T> {
  private Class<T> clazz;
  private Map<String, String> headers;
  private Map<String, String> params;
  private Listener<T> listener;

  public GsonRequest(Api api, Class<T> clazz, Listener<T> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    this(api, clazz, null, null, listener, errorListener);
  }

  public GsonRequest(Api api, Class<T> clazz, Map<String, String> params, Listener<T> listener,
      ErrorListener errorListener) {
    this(api, clazz, params, null, listener, errorListener);
  }

  /**
   * Make a GET request and return a parsed object from JSON.
   *
   * @param url
   *            URL of the request to make
   * @param clazz
   *            Relevant class object, for Gson's reflection
   * @param headers
   *            Map of request headers
   */
  public GsonRequest(Api api, Class<T> clazz, Map<String, String> params, Map<String, String> headers,
      Listener<T> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(api.method, api.url, errorListener);
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.params = params;
    this.headers = headers;
    this.listener = listener;
  }

  // use new GsonRequest()
  @Deprecated
  public GsonRequest(String url, Class<T> clazz, Map<String, String> headers, Listener<T> listener,
      ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(Method.GET, url, errorListener);
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.headers = headers;
    this.listener = listener;
  }

  @Override
  public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
  }

  @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {  
    Map<String, String> result = params;
    return result;
    }

  @Override
  public Map<String, String> getPostParams() throws AuthFailureError {   
    Map<String, String> result = params;
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
    listener.onResponse(response);
  }

  @Override
  protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
      String json = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, "utf-8"));
//      Log.d("zhch", json);
      return Response.success(GsonUtils.fromJson(json, clazz), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
      return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer assumes you are trying to make a GET request.

I had a similar issue. GET requests are a little different than POST when it comes to passing parameters when using Volley.
 when you make a GET request, ONE of the WAYS to pass the params is inside the url string itself, this worked for me :

(this is a partial example, but should give you most of what you need to modify your own code)

In the class that sends the requests I used a small method to append the params to the url:

```
//this method sits somewhere in your class
private String createGetWithParams(String url, Map<String, Object> params)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String key : params.keySet())
    {
        Object value = params.get(key);
        if (value != null)
        {
            try
            {
                value = URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(value), HTTP.UTF_8);
                if (builder.length() > 0)
                    builder.append("&");
                builder.append(key).append("=").append(value);
            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    return (url += "?" + builder.toString());
}


//this method sits somewhere in the same class, this fires the request
public void doSomeRequest()
{
    Map<String, Object> jsonParams = new HashMap<>();
    jsonParams.put("SomeParam", SomeParamValue);
    jsonParams.put("SomeOtherParam", SomeOtherParamValue);

    String url = createGetWithParams("some/request/url", jsonParams);

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response)
                {
                 // do whatever
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {
                    if (null != error.networkResponse)
                    {
                        Log.d(" Volley Error Response code: ", ""+ error.networkResponse.statusCode);
                    }
                }
            });

      requestQueue.add(request);
```

I Also created a custom request class that replaced the StringRequest, but that was to have more control over parsing the response - might help you though, in this class I only override the response:

```
public class CustomStringRequest extends StringRequest
{
 private final Response.Listener<String> mListener;

 public CustomStringRequest(int method, String url, Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener)
 {
    super(method,url, listener, errorListener);
    mListener = listener;
 }

 @Override
 protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response)
 {
     try
     {
         // response.data is the byte array, do whatever..
         String responseBody = new String(response.data, "utf-8");
         Log.d(" NetworkResponse", responseBody);

         return (Response.success(responseBody, getCacheEntry()));
     }
     catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
     {
         VolleyLog.e("UnsupportedEncodingException");
         Log.d("NetworkResponse Exception", e.getMessage() );
         return (null);
     }
 }

 @Override
 protected void deliverResponse(String response)
 {
     mListener.onResponse(response);
 }
```

}

the other way I know of is using a specific http client, I haven't used that way, but you could probably use OkHttp, or something similar.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. But I made a POST request. And the problem is the request  worked well at real device but cann't work at genymotion

Comment: can you elaborate some more? give some log prints? do you get any ErrorResponse or is the request not even leaving the emulator into the Network?

Comment: Sorry, there is no more infomation I can get. There is no err log and ErrorResponse, just error logic response for lack params(request was sent and processed by server). The same code installed at real device can worked.

Comment: Were you able to get around this? I'm having a similar issue that is preventing me from using Genymotion:

Comment: From what I know, there seems to be a known issue with volley and Genymotion, I usually test on live devices so it never happened to me, but I have heard about it happening