# volley how to parse params to JsonObjectRequest getParams does not work

Tags: android, android-volley

As an `old version` of `volley.jar`. I pass `params` by following method:

```
@Override
public byte[] getBody() {
    if (params != null && params.size() > 0) {
        return encodeParameters(params, getParamsEncoding());
    }
    return null;
}
```

But I need to update volley, and find that this method(encodeParameters()) was changed to private.

I also found that to override the method of `getParams()`, which did not work for me.  the Method `getBody` of `JsonObjectRequest` is as following:

```
public byte[] getBody() {
    try {
        return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes(PROTOCOL_CHARSET);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
        VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s",
            mRequestBody, PROTOCOL_CHARSET);
        return null;
    }
}
```

`getParams()` would never be called. so I cannot pass the `params` now.

I also tried to pass the `params` in the construct method which has `JsonObject` param, but it did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

hope I'm understanding you correctly.

an easier way to pass params with volley would be:

```
    String url = "some/url";

    Map<String, Object> jsonParams = new HashMap<>();
    jsonParams.put("someparam", getSomeParamObject());

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new JSONObject(jsonParams),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                {
                 //do your magic...
                }
            }
```

for the encoding issue, see if this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29761634/volley-customer-request-do-not-take-params/29793139#29793139) helps.

Hope this Helps.