# How to send multiple parameters from android app to search in database?

Tags: java, android, django, spring, android-volley

I am creating simple search application. I have search parameters in ArrayList that I want to use to make search in database. Every single time size of ArrayList would be different. I already have most of my application completed and this part made me completely stop.

I use Volley and my PHP for getting JSON from database and I read that I could also send parameters by Volley, but don't think it would work for me.

Friend told me that only way to make this is to use services (I still trying to understand what they are). I tried researching Django, Spring, but I cant understand what I can use them for, I'm so confused about this part.

I want to ask for your guidance for my specific problem, because I don't even know what I should be paying my attention searching in Google as there not so much tutorials for Spting framework or Django or other methods.

Comment: Volley allows for you to add parameters as well as a full post body to the request. It should be all you need as long as you have your PHP script(s) setup correctly and the server is configured to allow the request to come through.

Comment: @zgc7009 just to be clear, so I could pass to PHP an array by Volley with not specific number  of elements to make search query?

Comment: If I understand your question, yes you can send the PHP script whatever parameters you want to through Volley, how you manage those parameters is the responsibility of the PHP script itself.

Comment: have a look at this for volley usage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172496/android-volley-how-to-isolate-requests-in-another-class/30604191#30604191        and this for parameters usage through volley:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29761634/volley-request-not-taking-parameters/29793139#29793139